# Removing Bugtracker Integration from SVN\Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, tortoisesvn, bug-tracker, bugtracker.net

I have used TortoiseSVN_integration.bat to integrate SVN with Bugtracker and ultimately Visual Studio.

```
svn propset -R bugtraq:label "BugTracker.NET ID:" .
svn propset -R bugtraq:url "http://DOMAINNAME/edit_bug.aspx?id=%%BUGID%%" .
svn propset -R bugtraq:message "bugid: %%BUGID%%" .
svn propset -R bugtraq:number "true" .
svn propset -R bugtraq:warnifnoissue "true" .
svn commit -q -m "Added BugTracker.NET properties to the repository"
```

Also see the following pic:
http://oi62.tinypic.com/2u6ihww.jpg
I'd like to remove this integration as it's no longer needed.
How do I do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [propdel](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.propdel.html) to remove all bugtraq related properties, starting at the root of your working copy, or wherever you ran the batch file from.

Make sure you run include the -R option since your propset command was also recursive, then commit and you should be done.

Another option is to use Windows Explorer -> TortoiseSVN -> Properties on the root directory folder, then multi-select the bugtrack properties, click Remove, then Recursive, then commit.

Comment: I was able to EDIT the bugtraq:url property as well using "Windows Explorer -> TortoiseSVN -> Properties".  For me I just wanted to change bugtraq:url because our servername url changed so this was helpful (esp. the "Recursive" part).